# How to concatenate two vectors in Julia?

Tags: julia, concatenation

Given two vectors `a = [1, 2]` and `b = [3, 4]`, how do I obtain the concatenated vector `c = [1, 2, 3, 4]`?  It seems that `hcat` or `vcat` could be used as they work on arrays, but when using vectors to store collections of elements it seems unfitting to first think about the orientation of the data; it's just supposed to be a list of values.

Comment: `[a; b]` does vector concatenation.

Comment: @DNF this works and is elegant, would you turn this comment into an answer to give it more visibility?

Comment: It is only a synonym for `vcat`, though: cf. `Meta.@lower [a; b]`.

Comment: @phipsgabler Yes, but the naming/syntax seems to be the issue here, and I also personally prefer this to the 'lowered' version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most `Array` methods treat arrays as general "tensors" of arbitrary ranks ("data cubes"), so you *do* need to think about the orientation.  In the general case, there's `cat(a, b; dims)`, of which `hcat` and `vcat` are special cases.

There is another class of methods treating `Vector`s as list like.  From those, `append!` is the method that, well, appends a vector to another.  The problem is that it is mutable.  So you can, for example, `append!(copy(a), b)`, or use something like [`BangBang.NoBang.append`](https://github.com/JuliaFolds/BangBang.jl/blob/a32c7a8784e1d4b4e7d988aa1bc28045a312f003/src/NoBang/base.jl) (which just selects the right method internally, though).

For the case of more than two vectors to be concatenated, I like the pattern of

```
reduce(append!, (a, b), init=Int[])
```

Comment: Repeatedly appending seems like it would be much less efficient than `vcat` because preallocating the storage necessary is impossible, which means there will be many unnecessary allocations unless you `sizehint!` the `init` argument before passing it.

Comment: I think the `reduce` should be more efficient using `append!`, since you are only resizing one vector instanceusing a doubling strategy, which has constant amortized complexity and will lead to logarithmically many intermediate reallocations. With `vcat` it creates a new copy every time. But I haven't tested it at all...

Comment: No, `reduce(vcat, ..)` is faster (about twice as fast on my laptop, with fewer allocations). `reduce` has special implementations for `vcat` and `hcat`.

Answer (score 15):

You can write

```
[a; b]
```

Under the hood this is the same as `vcat`, but it's terser, looks better, and is easier to remember, as it's also consistent with literal matrix construction syntax.

An alternative for concatenating multiple vectors is

```
reduce(vcat, (a, b))
```